# How to place elements side by side each other, programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a spinner, checkbox, and eddittext. Currently they are all one under each other but I want to make it so they are side by side each other

For example:

the spinner on the left, the edittext on the right of the spinner and then the checkbox on the right of the edittext.

Is this possible to do this programatically because these elements are created programatically.

java code

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TextView> mTextviews = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EditText> mEdittexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<View> mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView textview;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout verticallayout,horizontalLayout;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    TextView newTextview;







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout).requestFocus();

        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout); //got






        //Arrays
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(String.valueOf(mSpinners)); // add you selected item
        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();




        //Initializing Variables Here
        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);
        //verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout);
        textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);





        //TODO getting shared prefs on create
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", null));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {



              /*  final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);*/

                final View newView = makeView();
                //Add a new view
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


              /* final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);



                final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);*/

                createRow();


                newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);











                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //TODO deleting item
                horizontalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);


                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            //mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            // mSpinners.remove(listSize - 1);

                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            // mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });





                int positionOfSpinner = (int) jsonArray2.get(i);
                spinner.setSelection(positionOfSpinner);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end of shared pref  code








        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);



                // Handle ze click.
               /* final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins(5, 100, 10, 0); //top 70

                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
                layoutParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
*/
                final View newView = makeView();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


               /* final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);*/

                createRow();

                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //code for deleting the said item.



                horizontalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);



                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            //mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.remove(listSize - 1);
                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            //mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });

                //Add a new checkbox
               /* final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);*/


                newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);

                //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                        String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                        //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                        //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                        newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        //  code here, do nothing
                    }

                });


            }
        });

    }



















    //TODO OVERFLOW MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            /*Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, AppCompatPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            //start the settings activity here.*/

            startActivity(new Intent(create.this, settings.class));





            return true;
        }


        else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            //code to delete list here.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }


        else if (id ==R.id.action_help)  {


            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Help");
            builder.setMessage("To use this app, first go to Create your Shopping List.\n" +
                    "Here, you can add items to your list. Once you have added all items, you can click the menu at the top right corner (or if it doesnt appear press your menu button beside your home button on your device, then click View your List.\n" +
                    "This will take you to the screen where you can view you shopping list with the items in aisle order to make your shop much easier.\n" +
                    "You can still add items at this point. Press the white background of each item to delete the item if you wish.");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


            return true;

        }




        else if (id == R.id.action_gotoview) {


            //takes the size of the list of spinners, for reference
            ArrayList<Integer> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
                spinnerList.add(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

            }
            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", spinnerList);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(create.this, viewscreen.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("extraBundle", newBundle);

            startActivity(newIntent);



            //code to go to view screen, aka intent
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }






    public void createRow(View view){

        createRow(); //got

    }


    private void createRow() { //got

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalParams.height = 80;
        horizontalParams.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 15); // LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);
        horizontalLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.addButtons));


        makeEdittext();
        makeCheckbox();
        makeSpinner();
        makeTextview();



        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout, horizontalParams);
    }







    //DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN FAB IS PRESSED//
    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
  /*      LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        //setup relative layout for the positioning of the objects
        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)), (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)));
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textview);

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkbox);


        return checkbox;
    }



    private TextView makeTextview() {
        //create new textview
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);

        //setup layout

/*        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        editParams.width = 70;
        editParams.height = 50;

        textview.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(textview);
        textview.setTextSize(30);

        return textview;
    }



    private EditText makeEdittext() {
        //create new edittext
        EditText edittext = new EditText(this);

        //setup layout
       /* final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 50); // Width , height
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);*/



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        editParams.width = 70;
        editParams.height = 50;

        edittext.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(edittext);


        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        edittext.setHint("qty");

        return edittext;

    }

//set the  3d effect to view

    private View makeView() {
        //create new View

        View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);


        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        view.setClickable(true);

        //view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        //setup layout

        return view;


    }














    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        //TODO I made this variable global, declared it at the very top of this file
        itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        // SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
        SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);


        // Setup layout

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

        spinnerParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
        spinnerParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);

    /*    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/



        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);





        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);



        //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                //  do nothing
            }
        });




        return spinner;
    }



    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


    //on stop, the things are saved into shared prefs
    @Override
    protected void onStop () {

        //public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
            jsonArray.put(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

        }

        editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
        editor.apply();


        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

at this line

```
            mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're creating these elements? and the xml layout

Comment: the `private` classes down the bottom

Comment: oh dear, can you clean out any unnecessary code :D ? Just post the minimal for people to work with to post an answer.

Comment: done :) is that better

Answer (score 1):

Set your linear layout orientation to horizontal

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/my_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn't work for my situation, because as I am adding these spinners and other elements, they are all placed horizontally to each other meaning it'll go way off the screen to the right. I just wanted it so they still are created below one another, but each set of elements (checkbox, spinner, edittext and textview) are placed horizontal to each other.

Comment: Ahh you could do nested LinearLayouts, one for the vertical grouping and 3 horizontal ones (for each row of items) or you could do a relative layout and specify which ones are to `layout_toRightOf`and `layout_below`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go and get back to you!

Comment: So I am trying to make this param for relative layout `                relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textview());
`  in the private CheckBox method. But since I want it to be right of textview, it does not work beacause textview variable is declared in another private method. Is there a way to still use this textviewvariable even though it is in a nother method if that makes sense.

Comment: you can make the textview and checkbox variables class variables declared outside of the private methods.

Comment: sorry how do I do that?

Comment: define them outside the methods but within the class declaration https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I declared `TextView textview;` at the top of my code but now I am getting this red error in my relative layout for `textview` - 'Wrong  2nd argument type. Found: android.widget.TextView required: "int"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

*home_activity.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="createRow"
        android:text="Create Row" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/verticalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*HomeActivity.java*

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout verticallayout, horizontalLayout;
    int width;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    }

    public void createRow(View view) {
        createRow();
    }

    private void createRow() {
        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);

        createSpinner();
        createCheckbox();
        createEditText();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }

    private void createEditText() {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3), convertDpToPixel(40));
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        editText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        editText.setHint("Enter something");
        editText.setTextSize(14f);
        horizontalLayout.addView(editText);
    }


    private void createCheckbox() {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3), convertDpToPixel(40));
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
//        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        checkBox.setText("Is Applicable");
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkBox);

    }

    private void createSpinner() {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3), convertDpToPixel(40));;
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
//        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        String[] item = new String[]{"item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);
    }


    public int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return dp * ((int) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    }

}
```

*may be this code generate some margin problem, but u can solve it by managing the value of `Params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)`*

let me know if any concern.

Comment: the margin works fine. i think it is just a problem with my spinner adapter or something like that. when I add the params onto my spinner and take out the add spinner to the view part in my code and replace that with createRow(), i get error.

Comment: this is my current code https://pastebin.com/LsHuJZsB i have successfully added parrams to edittext and the checkbox but I am having trouble with the spinner and the textview, because I use both of them outside the method for various things as well

Comment: let me check first.

Comment: i think you should use spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener under the makeSpinner method.

Comment: inside or outside and under it?

Comment: inside of makeSpinner.

Comment: Define it globally.

Comment: I get this error: https://pastebin.com/6QgsT1DU at this line                `newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);` and here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/YtcuArnT

Comment: as i said 'final TextView newTextview ' to define it under class not any method

Comment: you mean do this     final TextView newTextview;
 at the top of my code where other variaables are stated?

Comment: I havedone that. but im still getting  the same error for that same line. heres my updated code https://pastebin.com/mTykxch8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179674/discussion-between-aniruddh-parihar-and-magic-whizz).

Comment: I  posted in chat

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using a static Linear Layout in XML ( Vertical orientation ) and added horizontal rows of the elements dynamically.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:onClick="createRow"
        android:text="Create Row" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/verticalLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/button">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity to add Layout Dynamically

```
public class MyLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout verticallayout,horizontalLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_poc);

        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout);

    }

    public void createRow(View view){

        createRow();

    }

    private void createRow() {

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);

        createSpinner();
        createCheckbox();
        createEditText();

        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout);
    }

    private void createEditText() {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        editText.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(editText);
    }


    private void createCheckbox() {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkBox);

    }

    private void createSpinner() {

        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        //spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);
    }
}
```

Add the data to your spinner in array adapter according to your logic. you can change Layout params as per your design. My code gives output like  below image:

[image: Output]

Comment: thanks. that works for my edittext and checkbox but app crashes for spinner. I think I have to change some things around. i'll get back to you about it  :)

Comment: hi so I updated my code about the spinner..I get an error and app crashes. updated code in post

Comment: I have a similar issue with when i am adding the textview and a View box but i'll sort that out if I know what's wrong with the spinner I guess @kukroid

Comment: hello? i appreciate your help :)

Comment: It is issue in the code ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(String.valueOf(mSpinners)); // add you selected item
        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();------ Here you are taking value of mSpinners, where you have not assigned value to them , thats why you are gettign Null pointer exception

Comment: how would I fix that?

Comment: also in I have a createViews method as well, which creates a white box with the width of the screen and a height of like 50. is it possible to put the checkbox, and edittext and spinner and textview on top of the view/white box? @kukroid

Comment: never mind about putting them onto of  a View, I think I could just use the verticalLayout which is created for each yea?

Answer (score 0):

as other answers are suggesting you can always create views dynamically. but what I think you should do since you haven't accept any of these answers is to create your desired XML row and then you can add that view to your layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxmlrow, null, false);
linearLayout.addView(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your LinearLayout orientation to horizontal

```
mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: mLinearLayout is where I am adding *all* 'row's of elements. so If I set that to horizontal, *all* elements will go horizontal and I won't be able to see anything

Comment: I am trying to use kukroid's  and Aniruddh's answers. please see those. am having problem with spinner